# galaxy tab 7 vs nexus 7 different dimensions res folder

Tags: android-layout, screen

I am wondering how to set up my dimensions resources folder in order for my layouts to look good on Nexus 7 and first generation Samsung Galaxy 7 inch tablets. They both use values-large res folder, the only difference is that the Nexus 7 uses xhdpi and Galaxy 7 uses hdpi. How can I use separate dimensions folder for each one of the devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix, create two new layout folders in res: layout-large and layout-large-hdpi.
The galaxy 2 will use the layouts in layout-large, while the nexus 7 will use the layouts in layout-large-hdpi. However, this method is deprecated. For the correct way of doing this, you should refer to [the official android screen layout guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) which has been updated for 7" screens.