# Layout and drwable folders for Google Nexus and Galaxy tab (7 and 10)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am very confuse now for set layout and drawable folder. I want that my graphics support both Galaxy nexus 7 asus and Galaxy tab. I prepare a demo app first and what I saw both support hdpi folder with normal layout. But both have different resolution and density. so my graphics not good look in Galaxy tab. I search and find so many links and go through that but not working for me. Don't know what mistake i do. Please correct me or give me any suggestions.

Preferred link:  [galaxy tab 7 vs nexus 7 different dimensions res folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855128/galaxy-tab-7-vs-nexus-7-different-dimensions-res-folder)

[Layout folders for Google Nexus 7 and 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556800/layout-folders-for-google-nexus-7-and-10)

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus7 is a unique device, with a somewhat strange dpi structure.

For more than you probably need to know, here is a very good explanation (from Dianne Hackborn - an Android engineer at Google): [Dianne Hackborn explains the unique resolution of the Nexus7](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8)

The Nexus7 will use resources out of the xhdpi folder - and scale them for it's unique resolution.

This is the first time this has been done, so is definitely unique (and explains why you might be seeing strange behavior).

Comment: But Both Galaxy Tab 4 7" and Nexus 7" takes the value from tvdpi folders, but both are different screen size. It make the problem, now How Can I place values only for Nexus 7 and Tab 4 7"

Answer (score -1):

There may be two possible solutions.

**1.** First is you can use a new folder for the layout of the galaxy tab named **layout-sw600dp** and keep your layout xml file with new layout for galaxy tab.refer  [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).
**res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)**

**2.** The second solution may be that you manually find out the resolutions of the mobile and set the drawables for the resolution manually.

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int scrheight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int scrwidth = metrics.widthPixels;
            if(scrheight==1024 && scrwidth==600)
            {
            **set ur resources here**
            }
```

Comment: I was just telling you it may be a way.I am not confirm. Have you refer the link i have given it is given there....