# UI is not looking the same on Nexus 7 as on other Android devices

Tags: android

I have created anAndroid application UI which looks almost same on all Android devices except Nexus 7 and some other Android devices which fall in the same category.

I have read that some devices and some tablets require a special drawable folder in the application folder in IDE.
I have already created that folder and placed the images accordingly, but still it is not looking as good as on the other Android devices.

I have placed some text views according to the screen height and width, but even then it is not looking properly on those devices.

Comment: Screenshots? Please clarify your problem more clearly

Comment: In Android Studio there is an option called "Preview all screen sizes" in your layout xml design mode.

Comment: Also be aware that Nexus 7 2012 used tvdpi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348607/android-nexus-7-dpi-for-eclipse